# End request if error in PreRequestHandlerExecute

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute event in a web service.

In this event I currently do a layer of data validation and mutation before that data reaches the requested call.

Is there a way for me to end a request if I decide there is a error with the data?

I was hoping to prevent an invalid request from going to its destination, since that destination is going to fail any way. And its a very large code set written by someone else who I cannot refer too, so I didn't want to have to edit all 100+ calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that you can use HttpApplication.Context.Handler to redirect the request to, in my case, an error handling location.